# Is there a preferred tool to edit Gemfiles?

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I have a project that depends on Ruby to do something. I need to tell these people to install bundler, create a Gemfile (or update an existing one) and then run bundler install.

*To be very clear*, these people do not care about Ruby, they don't know what Ruby is and they don't need to know what Ruby is.

Currently my documentation is:

1. Run this command in terminal:

   ```
   gem install bundler
   ```
2. Create a new file name `Gemfile` and add these contents:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'lightning_sites'
   ```

   Or if there is already a `Gemfile` then edit that file and add the line `gem 'lightning_sites'` at the bottom.
3. Go back to the terminal and run:

   ```
   bundle install --path vendor/bundle
   ```

I would like to replace the documentation for step 2 and preferable replace it with a command line. Is there a tool that ships by default with Ruby or bundler that accomplishes this?

Comment: Here is an answer, I am not sure if it is robust. `bundle init; echo "gem 'lightning_sites'" >> Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid bundler you need to force-bundle all your dependencies inside your application. This is only really practical if none of your dependencies have compiled extensions, so if they're all pure Ruby you'll be able to do it.

What you end up doing is a `bundle install --path gems/` for example, then package up everything including that directory as a deployable application. You may want to make a script that performs this step and creates a `.zip` file of the final result for distribution purposes.

This is a heavy-handed approach, so it's best to do this only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Bundler to install gems, Ruby provides the `gem` command for installing gems individually.

You could simply run: `gem install lightning_sites --install-dir lightning_sites` and in whatever Ruby script is using the gem, programatically modify your `GEM_PATH` using `Gem.paths` before the `require` statement to include that install directory.